# Does angular dart have a built in function to remove illegal file-name characters from a string

Tags: angular-dart

In angular dart (using Visual Studio Code) If the user-clicks on a report such as "A/R Listing" to export to a CSV file. I need to remove the "/" from the name. I know I can just to a string replace for "/" but since the name of the report can be customized, it could be anything. Is there a function native to dart that knows which characters are illegal or does that all have to be done manually?
Thanks